# CUDA texture as a class member?

Tags: cuda, textures, cuda-arrays

Attempting to define a class with a per-instance texture. Yes, the number of instances of that class will be small. To work around the restriction that CUDA texture must be a global variable, I tried the following approach:

- Define a global table of textures.
- Add an instance-ID data member to the class.
- Have a class method select a texture from the table using its ID, and pass it as an argument to a CUDA kernel.

Doesn't work.  A texture cannot be passed as an argument (nor by pointer or reference), and the kernel doesn't recognize the array name, barring passing by index.
I could probably do it with a switch statement, but that is ugly.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GPU with Compute Capability >= 3.0, then you can use texture objects instead of texture references. You can then pass the texture object as a kernel/function argument or use it as a class member. See Cuda Programming Guide section B.8 or [Texture objects](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT.html#group__CUDART__TEXTURE__OBJECT).

In case you don’t have a device with CC 3.0 or above, I guess you’re out of luck and would need a, as you said, "ugly" switch statement in your kernel that chooses the right texture reference depending on some argument.

Comment: A switch statement is needed, but not within the kernel.

Comment: You’re right, when answering the question I thought of using multiple textures in the kernel and switch upon data on a per thread basis. But actually there’s no evidence the questioner wants to do this, why switching to the right texture reference before kernel launch is definitely the better choice.

Comment: To switch on a per thread basis, the best option would be to combine the textures into a large texture and then manipulate sampling positions within each thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the texture that you need before calling the kernel.

So, you have a single texture reference and any number of textures stored in, for instance, cuArrays. Before calling the kernel, you bind the reference to the cuArray that you need:

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> texRef;

if (need_texture_1) {
  cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray1, ...);
else if (need_texture_2) {
  cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray2, ...);
}
kernel<<<>>>();

__global__ void kernel() {
  var = tex2D<float>(texRef, ...);
}
```